# CakePHP Messaging System

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I'm trying to implement a simple messaging system in CakePHP 1.3. What I need to do is perform a query to return an array of users that my logged in user is having a conversation with (so has either received a message from, sent a message to, or both).

My User model is set up like so:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');

    var $hasMany = array(

        'SentMessages' =>
        array (
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'sender_id'
        ),

        'ReceivedMessages' =>
        array (
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'receiver_id'
        )
    );  
}
```

I can use Containable to retrieve just the User and their related messages, and add conditions to those Contain statements to limit those messages to the ones between each user and my logged in user.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'ReceivedMessages' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'receiver_id' => $my_user_id
            )
        ),
        'SentMessages' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'sender_id' => $my_user_id
            )
        )
    )
));
```

However, this still returns EVERY user in my DB. Is there a way to write this query so that only the Users with any SentMessages or ReceivedMessages are returned?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume `$my_user_id` is definitely set, and there are records for this ID. Check the output of the query - is cake actually applying the condition in the SQL? You could also try appending the table/model name to each conditions field in case Cake is looking for `receiver_id` in the users table.

Comment: Yeah, it's set. The conditions on the contain statement are working - only messages to or from $my_user_id are being retrieved. My problem is that $users contains every user from my DB, even those where SentMessages and ReceivedMessages are empty. I'd like those users not to be retrieved at all.

Comment: Ah, I expect in that case it's because you are doing a `User->find('all')`. I'll post something that may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new 'Conversation' entity like so:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Message' => array(
        'className' => 'Message',
        'foreignKey' => 'conversation_id'
    )
);

var $belongsTo = array(
    'FirstUser' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'first_user_id'
    ),
    'SecondUser' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'second_user_id'
    )
);
```

Then performing the following find:

```
$conversations = $this->Conversation->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Conversation.first_user_id' => $this->my_user_id,
            'Conversation.second_user_id' => $this->my_user_id
        ),
        'Conversation.modified >' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $since_timestamp)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $my_user_id),
    'contain' => array(
        'ReceivedMessages' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'receiver_id' => $my_user_id
            )
        ),
        'SentMessages' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'sender_id' => $my_user_id
            )
        )
    )
));
```

My reasoning is in your original code you are finding `all` but not specifying a condition for **that** find.

Cake is then returning ALL your users and any messages where they exist. I expect the `$users` array contained the correct data in the correct format, but you only require a specific users.

By adding the condition to the initial find you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I don't think I've been very clear on my desired result format. I've managed to get the right format by iterating over the array. http://pastebin.com/AiuuARpA is a quick dump of what I think the best output format would be. Does that make it any clearer?